# Flot: Subscript text in label

Tags: javascript, flot

I have already asked this question in offical Flot google groups, but got no answear. Maybe because it is more javascript oriented, here is the question:

I have added the following code in my code:

```
var j = "d";
j = j.sub();

plot1 = $.plot($("#grafTemp"), [
{label: "Rosišče (°C): T" + j + "(t) = ---.---°C"
```

.... the rest does not matter.

And:

```
legends.eq(i).text(series.label.replace(/=.*/, "= " + y.toFixed(2)  +"°C"));
```

I was using this example:
http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/tracking.html

Now, the subscript works ok, it displays T_d fine. But when I update
the graph (when user moves mouse over graph), then it displays

```
<sub>d</sub>
```

I know that the problem is at the legends.eq(i).text....., where
it returns pure string, with literal:

```
<sub>
```

I would like to know, how it would be possible to fix this issue. So it would use html element sub properly?

Comment: Is `legends` an HTML element? If so, maybe you're looking for the `html()` function instead of `text()`?

Comment: Yeah that was the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glancing at the code, it looks like you'd replace the use of [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (e.g., `legends.eq(i).text(...)`) with [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (`legends.eq(i).html(...)`). But you'd need to be sure that there aren't other generated bits of it that would be a problem (for instance, if this stuff generated a string that had a `<` or `&` in it, that would need to be converted to `&lt;` / `&amp;` respectively before being fed into the `html` function).